# Zoom in on a report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to build a pop up zoom in form which will zoom in on  a report embedded in a tab control embedded in a form.   My zoom in box control is called txtzoom.  The code i thought would work looks like the following

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
 Me.txtZoom = Forms("frmContactsSwitchboard").Report("rptContactPage05")!Note
End Sub
```

My plan is to be able to zoom into a field, and be able to edit it..  I am not sure if this is possible.

I would appreciate if someone who is familiar with this issue could please let me know what i can do to resolve it..
Cheers,
A

Answer (score 2):

Do you know about Access's built-in (but flawed) Zoom window? Try pressing Shift-F2 on a table, query, form, or report (in report view). Unfortunately, the font defaults to Tahoma 8pt and resets each time you close Access. So, the first Shift-F2 doesn't help much, but once you've changed the font size, the rest of the functionality is there. You may want to just give the user a label that suggests using Shift-F2 to zoom.

Comment: Yes i know about that..  Im not sure however that you can make edits to the field when looking at a report..  Perhaps thats part of the flaw.